# jQuery - get an image src, and add to anchor tag outside the image

Tags: jquery

I'm racking my brain trying to figure this one out. I have a variable number of thumbnails that have the same name as the full-size images, only in a different directory. I need to get the `<img src="">` truncate it down to its filename (I'm using substring) and then add that to a path, and then apply it to the `<a>` tag outside of the image.

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
$("#divName img").each(function(i, element){
```

To loop through each `<IMG>` tag.

I'm getting the filename with:

```
$(element).attr("src").substring(92).
```

The document structure is something like this:

```
<div id="divName">
   <a href="url"><img src="path"/></a><br/>
   <a href="url"><img src="path"/></a><br/>
   <a href="url"><img src="path"/></a><br/>
   <a href="url"><img src="path"/></a><br/>
</div>
```

So I need to get the value of "path" and add it to the "url" in the anchor tag outside of it for each one.

I hope I've been clear. Please Help!  Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#divName a > img").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().attr("href", this.src);
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/KEw2D/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I'll try it out when I get into work tomorrow!  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divName img").each(function(i, element){
        var path = $(element).attr("src");
        var ancURL = $(element).parent().attr('href');
        $(element).parent().attr('href',ancURL +path);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mYdxw/31/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#divName img").each(function(i, element) {
        var src = $(element).attr("src").substring(92);
        var href = $(element).parent().attr("href");
        $(element).parent().attr("href", href + "/" + src);
    })
})
```

Comment: All the answers suited my needs. This was closest to what I had to do for the exact filename. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#divName img").each(function() {
    this.parentNode.href = this.src;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KEw2D/2/